# CI/CD results don't consider whether containers started successfully internally

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

When I bring up a Docker container in detached mode, the results usually return sooner as they will not print out on the console. This is a problem for me when I'm running it through Gitlab's CI/CD.

So for example, when I have this command in the deployment stage of my `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
ssh root@123.123.123.123 docker-compose up -d
```

This brings up all the containers in docker-compose in detached mode on my instance at the IP address. The console will usually output:

```
MyContainerA ... Done!
MyContainerB ... Done!
<exit>
```

To Gitlab CI, the deployment stage is completed successfully because there were no errors.

However, in reality, this doesn't guarantee that everything is good because the container may not have started up successfully internally. For example, the `npm start` may have failed and the container exits the next moment.

This makes the CI results (success/failed) to be unreliable. Is this normal when it comes to deploying Docker containers through CI/CD?

What should the correct way to deploy a Docker container through Gitlab CI/CD (or any other CI/CD per se) such that the CI's final result (success/failed) considers whether the containers actually started up successfully internally or not?

Comment: what do you want to check? if the docker-compose up finished successfully? you will need to define what does successful mean in your context - is the containers are up after 1 minute? or still up after 15 minutes? then you can write some kind of script that checks it (docker ps... )

Comment: @Amityo For a number of times, after docker-compose up is completed, the container exited after a while because some of the scripts that it attempts to run threw errors. Usually this happens within the next 5mins. But how do I know if a container has an error internally at Gitlab CI’s level?

Comment: i'm not sure that I understand - the ssh stage is to deploy the services to your testing/development or production env right? if not and it's part of the CI process (Gitlab CI level as you said) there are other, and better ways to set up containers (gitlab ci images + services), can you clarify?

Comment: @Amityo Yes, the ssh stage is to deploy the containers to production env. This is down at Gitlab CI level. The `docker-compose up` is run as a command through ssh at Gitlab CI level against my production instance. However, sometimes, the deployed containers tend to fail within itself and these failures are unknown to Gitlab CI. So Gitlab CI’s result would show “success” because it only knew up to the point after `docker-compose up` was completed. So, I’m wondering whether it’s a common practice for Gitlab CI or any CI to not know if a container had errors internally?

Comment: OK, I'm unfamiliar with a way to make sure that Docker compose up -d succeeded. In my case I use kubernetes for rolling update and I wrote a script that checks whether the update finished successfully. You will probably need to do the same but at a 'Docker level' - use Docker ps /Docker compose ps and make sure the containers run as expected. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Amityo I think I might get what you mean. So, when you deploy your containers to the pods or deployments, there might be cases where the containers may just fail to start within itself and those failures aren't captured by the CI. For these cases, do you mean like you write a script which the CI will run and wait out for a couple of mins then check the statuses of the containers using `docker ps` before return an exit code for the final result of the pipeline? Did I get you correctly?

Comment: Yes. in my case the infrastructure (kubernetes) provides an api for the deployment - (available replicas, updating, unavilable), and I have a script that query the api and waits for completion